# Dim String and custom text together in code line

Tags: vb.net

I need help

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(DLLink1, DownloadDirectory1)

If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then  
     TextBox4.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath  
End If  

Dim DownloadDirectory1 As String 
DownloadDirectory1 = Trim(TextBox4.Text)
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(DLLink1, DownloadDirectory1/UpdatedClient.zip)
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm really bad with formatting questions here. I tried, failed, and got   a downvote. :c  
But pretty much DownloadDirectory1 is a directory like
C:\
But If I leave it like that, it won't work because the file won't have a name  
So I need to make it DownloadDirectory1/UpdatedClient.Zip

Comment: I dont understand the problem - use `Path.Combine` to create the destination and pass it.  Also read this: [Ask]  - there is no question here, we are left to sort out what we think you might want to do.

Comment: If I do this:  DownloadDirectory1/UpdatedClient.zip)
It fixes it to DownloadDirectory1 / UpdatedClient.zip) and gives me a error.

Comment: My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(http://DownloadFileFromHere.com, C:\UpdatedFile.zip)    
That is what it looks like normally. But I want to make it where the user can change the download website and the location. So I did Dim DownloadDirectory1. But that makes the code My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(http://DownloadFileFromHere.com, C:\UpdatedFile.zip)   
So it's missing UpdatedFile.zip

Comment: **use `Path.Combine` to create the destination full filename and pass that**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this :

`My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(DLLink1, (DownloadDirectory1 + "/UpdatedClient.zip"))`

Comment: Yep! Thanks so much. That's exactly what I ment. Didn't know how to explain it though.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to combine strings to form a path is to use the Path.Combine method.

```
Dim myPath as String = System.IO.Path.Combine(DownloadDirectory1, "UpdatedClient.zip")
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(DLLink1, myPath)
```